# Python "requests" module errors sending follow request on Instagram

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

I am using the following script:

```
import requests
import json
import os

COOKIES = json.loads("") #EditThisCookie export here (json) to send requests 
COOKIEDICTIONARY = {}

for i in COOKIES:
    COOKIEDICTIONARY[i['name']] = i['value']

def follow(id):
    post = requests.post("https://instagram.com/web/friendships/" + id + "/follow/", cookies=COOKIEDICTIONARY)
    print(post.text)

follow('309438189')

os.system("pause")
```

This script is supposed to send a follow request to the user, `'3049438189'` on Instagram. However, if the code is run, the post.text outputs some HTML code, including

> "This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your
>   browser, or you are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling
>   cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action."

It's supposed to append the cookies to the variable, `COOKIEDICTIONARY` in a "requests" module readable format. If you print the array (I don't know what it's called in Python), it replies with all of the cookies and their values.

The cookies put in are valid and the requests syntax (I believe to be) is correct.

Comment: `json.loads()` expects a string argument. I'm surprised this code would even run. It certainly doesn't look like you would have anything in `COOKIES` or in `COOKIEDICTIONARY` which would explain why you got an error saying you're missing cookies.

Comment: I give it a string, the JSON export (in string form) of my EditThisCookie cookies for instagram. I remove the whitespace for it to fit on one line, and, if printed, shows all of my cookies in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. The problem was certain headers that I needed were not present, such as Origin (I will get the full list soon). For anybody who wants to imitate any instagram post request, you need those headers or it will error.